# reboot command not working from SSH

Tags: server, dns, reboot

Today I changed the DNS on my Ubuntu 20.04 server to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4, I then ran sudo reboot. The server did not actually restart and now trying to authenticate through SSH is met with a 5 minute hang. When I did finally get in, the system did not reboot. I am now trying to run reboot as the root user and running the reboot command results in the ssh terminal hanging for a few minutes and then seemingly nothing happens, no output nothing. 'who -b' returns the last boot time as several months ago.

Not sure what to do, I don't want to do a force shutdown and I would like to reboot the server to fix the ssh hang.

I should mention my DNS is not working. 'ping google.com' returns 'ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

systemd was not responding, reboot -f was able to get it restarted.